# RegEx: How to apply a Character Set restriction to a whole Expression

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, non-greedy

Let's say I have a regex which is used to validate email addresses, such as:

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

Now, let's say I also want to make sure that the following character set applies to the whole string too:

```
[\x00-\x7F]
```

How would I go about applying this 2nd character set restriction to the whole pattern.

Result would be that:

- jake.howlett@howlett.house (passes)
- jake.howẟlett@howlett.house (fails, as the ẟ is outside of the 2nd character set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add it in a positive lookahead after checking the start of string:

```
^(?=[\x00-\x7F]+$)your_pattern_here
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

After checking the start of string position with `^`, `(?=[\x00-\x7F]+$)` will be executed once and will require the whole string to be composed of only ASCII chars (note `+` matches 1 or more occurrences, and `$` tests the end of string position).

The regex will look like

```
^(?=[\x00-\x7F]+$)(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ify4mb/1)